# Material Design Lite - Multi-select dropdown

Tags: material-design, material-design-lite

How do you create a multi-select dropdown using the material design lite library? I can't seem to find anything on this.

I'm basically after something like this: **codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101**

Comment: This may be helpful: [How to format select box with Material Design Lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307764/how-to-format-select-box-with-material-design-lite)

Comment: Not really helpful @benvc. Doesn't contain anything about multi-select. I can get a standard dropdown working but there doesn't seem to be a way to implement a dropdown menu where you can select multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment it still doesn't support multi-select.